# What the way to query the reliable collection(IReliableDictionary) in Service Fabric?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, reliable-dictionary

we have scenario where reliable dictionary holds around 100000 records, each record contains bool property indicates whether its active or inactive record. i need to fetch only active record from the collection.

I used below method

```
IReliableDictionary<string, AlertEntity> storeAlert = await this.stateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<string, AlertEntity>>(TargetSolution.Names.AlertsRegistryStore);
using (ITransaction tx = this.stateManager.CreateTransaction())
{
                IAsyncEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, AlertEntity>> enumerable = await storeAlert.CreateEnumerableAsync(tx, EnumerationMode.Ordered);
                IAsyncEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, AlertEntity>> enumerator = enumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator();
                while (await enumerator.MoveNextAsync(appLifetime.ApplicationStopping))
                {
                    if (enumerator.Current.Value.ISActive)
                    {
                        alerts.Add(enumerator.Current.Value);
                    }
                }
                await tx.CommitAsync();
}
```

As per my understanding above code iterates each record to identify the IsActive property to true which i feel is time consuming.

So is There Any way to optimize this code using filter or LINQ query?

Can anybody help!!!!

Thanks for your Response :)

Comment: Side note: how about using two collections, one for active and one for inactive entities? Makes querying a lot easier/faster.

Comment: Seems like good approach.

Comment: Yes, was about to propose the same thing

Comment: Found one more approach for defining reliable collection
https://medium.com/@antoniomenarde/start-querying-your-azure-service-fabric-reliable-collections-today-bff755a1d4ae